# Select all rows between specific row values in a within columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to select all the rows of data between rows with these values in E01032739 and E01033708, does anyone know how to do this. Trying to do this so i can count the number of casualties between these area codes.

At the minute i can find all of the data with each set of values but cannot modify the code to get everything in between using this;

```
 accidents.loc[accidents['LSOA_of_Accident_Location'] == 'E01032739']
 accidents.loc[accidents['LSOA_of_Accident_Location'] == 'E01033708']
```

Data snippet here if needed;

```
Accident_Index  Number_of_Casualties    LSOA_of_Accident_Location
97459           34                      E01032739
97461           32                      E01033708
97762           12                      E01033708
```

Comment: Are the `LSOA_of_Accident_Location` in lexicography order ?

Comment: Yes they are in my dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be concise enough:

```py
accidents.query("'E01032739' <= LSOA_of_Accident_Location <= 'E01033708'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
accidents[(accidents['LSOA_of_Accident_Location'] >= 'E01032739')&(accidents['LSOA_of_Accident_Location'] <= 'E01033708')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does the job:

```
from_index = list(accidents[accidents["LSOA_of_Accident_Location"] == "E01032739"].index)[0]
to_index = list(accidents[accidents["LSOA_of_Accident_Location"] == "E01033708"].index)[0]

accidents.iloc[from_index: to_index + 1, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without a dummy datset, but I think this should work:

```
bottom_idx = accidents[accidents['LSOA_of_Accident_Location'] == 'E01032739'].index.values.astype(int)[0]
upper_idx = accidents[accidents['LSOA_of_Accident_Location'] == 'E01033708'].index.values.astype(int)[0]
accidents.iloc[bottom_idx:upper_idx]
```